# Distinguisihing normal text from a youtube link Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello all i am making a facebook clone using ruby on rails,
I got a post form where i can write text and add a youtube link if i want and it works. However writing a text like "hello world"+ "www.youtube.com/etc" would be output as "hello worldwww.youtube.com/..."
If i would just write "hello world" it would make a iframe for a youtube video which isnt correct either.

My application helper

```
def embed(youtube_url)
  youtube_id = youtube_url.split("=").last
  content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}")
end
```

In my view

```
<p><%= embed post.content %></p>
```

My question is how could i make an if else statement to see if a youtube url is present, if so show the video but hav it on its own "block" and the text separate, if no video dont display the iframe and just the normal text that i write.

Current output:

```
    <div class="post-content">
Hello World this is a sample text
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3dVpRAmq_8<br>
<p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/X3dVpRAmq_8"></iframe></p>
</div>
```

I want to have it show like

This is a sample text

But a if /else statement, if there is a youtube video present add it but in its own

tag, if no video is present just show the normal content i add

Comment: Could you post a generated html, which you have and which you want?

Comment: How it looks right now
`code`
<div class="post-content">
            Hello World this is a sample text
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3dVpRAmq_8<br>
            <p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/X3dVpRAmq_8"></iframe></p>
        </div>
`code`

I want to have it show like
<p>This is a sample text</p>
<iframe 'insert video here'>
<br/>
But a if /else statement, if there is a youtube video present add it but in its own <p> tag, if no video is present just show the normal content i add

Comment: You got to use `Regex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to approach this problem. Implement a presenter or create a helper method.

For the second approach, you would pass the input as a parameter to the helper method. You can determine what kind of content you're dealing with by using a regex to check for the existence of a you tube link. Here's a quick example

```
def my_helper_method(string)
  text, link = string.partition(/(w{3}.youtube.com\/watch\?v=\w*)/)
  output = ""
  output += "<p>#{text}</p>" unless text.empty?
  output += "<iframe src='#{link}</iframe>'" unless link.empty?
  output
end
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a useful site for experimenting with regexes.

Here's how you could use it with content_tag

```
def test_helper(string)
  text, link = string.partition(/(https:\/\/w{3}.youtube.com\/watch\?v=\w*)/)
  text_html = text.empty? ? nil : content_tag(:p, text)
  iframe = link.empty? ? nil : content_tag(:iframe, nil, {src: embed_code(link)} )
  text_html + iframe
end

def embed_code(string)
  code = string.split("v=").last
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{code}"
end
```

Comment: I  will try this out thank you! i visited the rubular site but it was kinda hard to understand it at first point!

Comment: I dont think this work well, because it just prints out the youtube as a string 
and the <p> tags as a string too so its not a block element

Comment: As I wrote above, this is an example to give you a flavour of you can determine the post contents. You will need to amend it for your specific requirements.

Comment: I've edited my solution to show how you could use it with content_tag